# vim edited macro adding a ^J at the end

Tags: vim, vim-macros

I was trying out "continuing macros despite error" as mentioned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15142/31628).
My test code looks like this

```
this is line number 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
this is line 6
this is line 7
this is word 8
this is line 9
this is line 10
this is line 11
```

where I have already recorded below macro on the first line. This macro basically appends the text  " *number*" after the first "*e*" find result and then goes and sits at the start of the the next line. (`^[` is the Escape key.)

`fea number^[j0`

As per the above link, I modified this to

`:try|norm fea number^[j0|catch||endtry^M`

I want to run this macro to the end of the file, where it will not find the "*e*" character on line 8 but still continue due to the `:try` command.

The `:try` function works correctly, but overall the edited macro does not work as intended (it does something extra). On checking with `:registers` the same macro contents look like this

`:try|norm fea number^[j0|catch||endtry^M^J`

The additional and unexpected `^J` makes the 2 lines join (not what I intend). Basically this, if ran on line 2 -

```
this is line number 1
this is line number 2 this is line 3
this is line 4
```

Where did this `^J` come from ? What am I doing wrong? And how can I make this macro work as intended?

I tried this in git bash as well as in gvim (both on windows).
Additionally `:set ff?` results in `fileformat=unix`.

Comment: How do you store those "macros"? How do you use them?

Comment: @romainl I simply do a `:let @g=':try|norm fea number^[j0|catch||endtry^M'` on the vim command line to edit and save the macro in register `g`. Then I run it using `@g`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect use case for `:help global`:

```
:g/^this is line/norm fea number
```

Comment: Nice. While this works for my above test code, the main question (about the unintended `^J` remains unanswered. :(